# Chisel: How to wait for signal assertion in ChiselScalatestTester?

Tags: chisel

I want to create a testbench for my Chisel-based module. So I'm using ChiselScalatestTester to create the testbench. My module use a custom protocol to communicate with the outside world. So inside the test class I have to wait for some signals to be asserted from DUT. Here is an example from my test class:

```
...
while (dut.io.outBusy) {
    dut.clock.step()
}
...
```

Would someone please help me implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you almost have it. Try

```
...
while (dut.io.outBusy.peek().litToBoolean) {
  dut.clock.step()
}
...
```